# Javascript paste event - getting file name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

The paste event files come back with a generic name such as 'image.png' (inside `file.name` on the `File` object and `items.getAsFile().name`) and that isn't super useful for me. I wrote the following code to get the name of the file I've pasted but it seems dirty and a bit of a hack, is there a better way to do this ?

Codepen example: 
https://codepen.io/designalchemy/pen/mddvbyV?editors=1010

How it works :

1. get items (`DataTransferList`) and files (`FileList`) from paste event
2. use `.getAsString()` method from the first item in the `DataTransferList` to get the file name
3. as this method destroys the `.getAsFile` method use the File from files object
4. rename file by cloning and applying the name

My code:

```
window.addEventListener('paste', onPasteEvent)

  const onPasteEvent = async e => {
    stopDefaults(e)
    const { items, files } = e.clipboardData

    // the .getAsString destorys the file object on 'items'
    // also can only do one paste at a time, no multi

    const file = files[0]
    const fileType = file.type

    if (file && fileType.includes('image')) {

      const fileName = await new Promise(res => {
        items[0].getAsString(e => {
          res(e)
        })
      })

      // clone file so we can change the name
      const newFile = [new File([file], fileName, { type: fileType })]

      if (newFile && newFile.length > 0) {
        callback && callback(newFile)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are saying `file.name` is a generic name?

Comment: @FelixKling yes, on the paste event, the file.name is always generic, this is part of a react component that allows drop and drop, file up load and paste, however the paste file.name is always generic.

Comment: This is a wonderful question. I have the same doubt. Upvoting right now.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: (although I am not sure if it fits your need)

I use FormData …
('say' is my private 'prettyprint',and code is Coffescript)

```
        current_file=evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.files[0]
        say "bad bad!",current_file
        formData= new FormData
        formData.append("myfile",current_file,"my name")
        current_file=formData.get("myfile")
        say "tada!", current_file
```

output:

```
  'bad bad!', File(name:'image.png' size:16203 type:'image/png')
  'tada!', File(name:'my name' size:16203 type:'image/png')
```

This is fast and synchronous.

I hope this helps and is self explaining.
If not tell me.